# Site.master does not see methods in Site.master.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have web app, which has site master 'Adminka.Master'.

Its code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Adminka.master.cs" Inherits="Kaifarik.Pages.Admin.Adminka" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/AdminStyles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1>Kaifarik: админ-панель</h1>
        <div class="adminContent">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="<%= OrdersUrl %>">Управление заказами</a>      ### The name 'OrdersUrl' does not exist in current context
        <a href="<%= DishesUrl %>">Управление каталогом EDOI</a> ## The name 'DishesUrl' does not exist in current context
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that OrdersUrl and DishesUrl methods can't bee seen in Adminka.master.cs file.

Adminka.master.cs code:

```
namespace Kaifarik.Pages.Admin
{
    public partial class Adminka : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public string OrdersUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return generateURL("admin_orders");
            }
        }

        public string DishesUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return generateURL("admin_dishes");
            }
        }

        private string generateURL(string routeName)
        {
            return RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, routeName, null).VirtualPath;
        }
    }
}
```

I created site master and didnt change inherits from default, yet still I get an error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrVF5.png)

[Here is structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZuDW.png)

I tried to regenerate designer file, change paths.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may try to bind URL with [HyperLink.NavigateUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_HyperLink_NavigateUrl) from code behind.

Comment: @YongShun Thanks for advice, but I dont have any idea how to do it with that for my needs :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the URL with [HyperLink.NavigateUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_HyperLink_NavigateUrl) from code behind.

> Adminka.master.cs

```
namespace Kaifarik.Pages.Admin
{
    public partial class Adminka : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             OrdersHyperlink.NavigateUrl = this.OrdersUrl;
             DishesHyperlink.NavigateUrl = this.DishesUrl;
        }

        public string OrdersUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return generateURL("admin_orders");
            }
        }

        public string DishesUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return generateURL("admin_dishes");
            }
        }

        private string generateURL(string routeName)
        {
            return RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, routeName, null).VirtualPath;
        }
    }
}
```

> Adminka.master

Replace your `<a>` element with `<asp:HyperLink>`. `<asp:HyperLink>` will generate `<a>` element in the HTML.

And apply `Target="_self"` to open the page in the current frame.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="OrdersHyperlink" runat="server" Text="Управление заказами" Target="_self" />
<asp:HyperLink ID="DishesHyperlink" runat="server" Text="Управление каталогом EDOI" Target="_self" />
```

References:

- [HyperLink.NavigateUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_HyperLink_NavigateUrl)
- [HyperLink.Target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_HyperLink_Target)